# Want to check if a string contains the -

Tags: regex, if-statement, regex-lookarounds

I am having some trouble figuring out how to check if the line contains a dash (`-`) and then capturing a part of it.

Here is an example of strings that I can have as input:

```
abc,xyz,ijk-a,opq

abc,xyz,ijk,opq
```

I want to extract the part before the dash, if it's present, namely `ijk`.
If there is no dash, I just want `ijk` (as shown in the second string).

The following regex expression uses if condition with lookahead assertion and does the job but always generates one empty group as shown here [Regex code here](http://regex101.com/r/nB8dQ7).
I would like to have only one capturing group returning `ijk`.

I thought that the regex if condition would only return the group of the if or else condition and not both.

```
.*,(?(?=.*?-.*?)(.*?)-.*?|(.*?)),
```

Thanks

Comment: After seeing another answer, I realized I needed clarification. Are the comma separated strings all on one line, and you can always have an option -something after each string?

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl style regex:

```
/[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,-]*)/
```

Example using two given cases:

```
perl -lane 'print $1 if /[^,]*,[^,]*,([^,-]*)/;' input
```

Output

```
ijk
ijk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `'([^-]+)(-([^-]+))?'`
Your string, followed by a hyphen or not, will be in the first capture group.

Comment: `-` is a special character. Escape it with `\\`.

Comment: - is special only inside [] and only if it is not the last character inside []